# Use a string as a variable in C?

Tags: c, variables

A simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
char *phrase = "Hello World";
char *var = "phrase"

printf("%s", var)
```

Desired output:

```
Hello World
```

I want the value of `var`, which is "phrase", to be substituted as a variable name, meaning that it would print the value of `phrase`. Is this even possible?

Comment: I think you want: `char *var = phrase;` [_without_ the quotes]

Comment: No C language will not parse the strings to find the variables. It is not possible. You need to write your own parser for that.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want something like: `char *var = "phrase"; char *value = find_address_of_symbol(var); printf("%s",value);`, then, no, it's _not_ possible [without a function that can examine the symbol table of its own executable]. That's an advanced technique, at best. And, not always possible. So, the `TL;DR` is _no_.

Comment: It might be possible with a macro

Comment: @byxor show an example

Comment: @byxor no it is not.

Comment: @Craig Estey is the right answer, and you're missing a couple of semicolons.

Comment: C is statically typed, so all variable names must be known at compile time

Answer (score 0):

```
char *phrase = "Hello World";
char *var = phrase ;
    printf("%s", var) ;
```

var now is a pointer to phrase pointer which is an array of chars